# Calculated field in Jira depends on another field

Tags: jira

I have issues in Jira, and the issues have assignees. Can I calculate the value of a custom field base on those assignee's names?
I.e, if assignee= name1, name2 or name3, set custom field value to Entity1, and if assignee = name4, name5 or name6, set the field to Entity2.
I want this to be changed automatically each time an assignee from corresponding entity is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the change to be made when making a workflow transition, use [Jira Script Runner plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) to add a post script function:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
cf = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Custome field name")
# get the current assignee
assignee = issue.getAssignee().getDisplayName()

if (assignee == 'John Doe'):
    # set vustome field 
    issue.setCustomFieldValue(cf, "content")
else:
    .....
```

If you want it the custom field to change the same moment the user changes the assignee, you can add an [AJS](http://orangoo.com/labs/AJS/) script to the assignee field description, let me know if you wand a code for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Script Runner plugin.